# Can you use V-ます before から？

Tags: grammar, particle-から

I was taught that you must use the plain form of a verb before から. Recently I've noticed that I will use the ます form of verbs.  Most often I'm saying ～がありますから instead of ～があるから。 I feel like it's not right but it comes out so naturally. I'm worried that it seems natural because it's become a habit that no one has ever corrected.

I know that you can use ～ですから to end a sentence, so is ～ますから also grammatically correct?

Comment: Basically, yes. It just makes the sentence more polite.

Comment: @Lyle Yes, but it's more complicated than "yes" or "no", so hopefully someone will write a more detailed answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

No, at least not always.

**It is correct** to use 「～～ますから」 in stand-alone statements expressing a reason-and-result or cause-and-effect relationship.

「[明日]{あす}また[来]{き}**ます**から、このパソコンはここに[置]{お}いておきますね。」"I am leaving this PC here because I will come back tomorrow again."

**It is NOT correct, however,** to use 「～～ますから」 followed by 「です」 in an answer stating a reason/cause to a question asking for such.

Person A:「なんでこういう[音楽]{おんがく}が[好]{す}きなの？」"Why do you like this kinda music?"

Person B:「[心]{こころ}が[落]{お}ち[着]{つ}き**ます**からです。」← ***Incorrect***

Person B should have said 「心が落ち着くからです。」"Because it relaxes me."

Comment: Would be better to say "Yes but" than "No". Specially if the OP is asking about sentences where it is ok to do so.

Comment: So then as long as I don't use together with です, then it is correct? Are there any other situation where I can't use it that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

yes ~ますから　can also be used as well as ～ですから both mean because

Comment: become both mean ... ? I'm not quite sure what comes after that for your answer.